# Deserialize JSON into readable format

Tags: c#, json, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am now working on a Xamarin project and I am using Firebase as my database.

I have a set of data as following:

[image: sample data]

I have managed to retrieve the data via RESTful service. However, when I tried to `JsonConvert.Deserialize` them, I am faced with an error telling me that I cannot convert to `.NET Collection`.

Is there a way I can do it?

My Model

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public bool Done { get; set; }

}
```

Retrieving from RESTful service

```
public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync()
{
    Items = new List<TodoItem>();

    //RestUrl = refer to constants.cs
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));

    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR{0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return Items;
}
```

UI

```
listView.ItemsSource = await App.TodoManager.GetTasksAsync();
```

> Update

What's in the content of variable `content`

```
{\"-L9K-8AF9fxZfe6bwTjk\":{\"Done\":false,\"ID\":\"323642ac-89e2-4f14-b9b0-e9b7306aee81\",\"Name\":\"ufhd\",\"Notes\":\"nvnv\"},\"-L9K07oNjtvPQYbdyItU\":{\"Done\":false,\"ID\":\"c7a53ad2-533f-454c-9ac0-5b21c3d2669c\",\"Name\":\"abc\",\"Notes\":\"cde\"},\"-L9K1n1r7Q7ZIgA3KFaD\":{\"Done\":false,\"ID\":\"938bd62f-f117-4733-a1e4-a4ed22233ca3\",\"Name\":\"ffef\",\"Notes\":\"dfg\"}}
```

Comment: Don't you need another model class that keeps track of this key `user`?

Comment: what is the actual string content of the 'content' variable before it attempts to deserialise?

Comment: @RomeoSierra do I? They have to be the same name or different is ok?

Comment: @AppPack Let me update for you

Comment: is that coming from an api you own? it's not in the format you would expect for a list of items. which would be why it's failing to deserialise

Comment: @AppPack I was just following the tutorial from Xamarin, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest but it couldn't work so I had to ask here..

Comment: oh yeah, romeo was right you need to account for the user

Comment: @AppPack aite, i will give a change now and update you of any change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from both first screenshot and from your json string - json you receive does not actually represent a collection. It's an object with cryptic properties, each property represents one todo item.

So you need to deserialize it as dictionary:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TodoItem>>(content);
```

If you don't care about those cryptic property names, you can do:

```
Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TodoItem>>(content).Values.ToList()
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `Dictionary` feature.. thank you so much, spent half my day trying to crack this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a complement to [Evk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669472/3126973).

I have taken the liberty of minifying your example dataset for the sake of brevity. This little example I have verified for the functionality.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var JSONStr = "{\"user\":{\"L9k0\":{\"ID\":\"001\", \"name\":\"somename\"},\"L9k1\":{\"ID\":\"002\", \"name\":\"someothername\"}}}";
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(JSONStr);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class JsonResult {
    public Dictionary<string, ToDoItem> user { get; set; }
}

class ToDoItem {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```