# How to access object data c# (Firebase)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I get data from my database (Firebase database). This is a document with several data, including a Array with GeoPoint fields.

```
var documents = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current .Instance .Collection("Activity") .GetAsync();
```

My object is defined like this in my Model class: `public class Activity { public object elapsedTime { get; set; } public object positions { get; set; } ...... }`

It works. I can have the data on my Activity class.
However, I would like to know how I can access this data because foreach loops do not work for object types. Maybe I need to redefine my Activity Class ?
Thx :=)

Edit :
You can see here my firebase : [image]

And then the result of the request :[image]

Comment: if your data is an  `Array with GeoPoint fields` then yes, defining it as an `object` in your class is probably incorrect

Comment: @Jason So what is the best solution for me ? I stuck at this point for 1 day ... Thx

Comment: create a C# class that accurately reflects the json data stored in Firebase.  You didn't post any detail about your actual data so I can't suggest any concrete fixes.

Comment: @jason My questino as been updated

Comment: there are numerous sites - json2csharp.com or VS iteself that will generate a C# class from json.  I suggest you use one of these tools

Comment: Not yet ! But I will. Thx for your time :)

Comment: Also you can google `json deserialize .net` There are several approaches; I've had good success with NewtonSoft's. The one built in to .Net - [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) is also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ! :)

To do it, I defined Array (from firestore) as IEnumerable on my C# class, with the same name from firestore to c#.

[image]

And then, here is my query and the line to get my objects converted.
[image]

Comment: Just what I needed.. been stuck on this for days on Xamarin -_-

Comment: Please do not post images on SO see why its wrong to post images here  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario , the property is dynamic for each object , I would suggest you deserialize the root level as a `dictionary`and then get the data you want .

```
Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, YourClass>>(content).Values.ToList()
```

Oh before this, [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) plugin is required .

Refer to

[Deserialize JSON into readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668960/deserialize-json-into-readable-format)

Comment: So I'm a bit lost ... My content is a IQuerySnapshot. So I can't use DeserializeObject right ?

Comment: I guess  you need data mapping : https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore#data-mapping , you can set `positions ` as `Array` type , so that it could be retrieved .